# Spring Data: How to save entity when field spit between two classes

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data

for creation of entity I use 2 classes:

Basic class for all my entities (w/o any annotation on the class level)

```
public abstract class AbstractEntity {

@Column(name ="date_of_creation",nullable = false)
private LocalDateTime dateOfCreation;

@Column(name="date_of_disable")
private LocalDateTime dateOfDisable;

@Column(name="date_of_update")
private LocalDateTime dateOfUpdate;

@Column(name="version_update")
private Integer updateVersion;
```

and the entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "cars")
public class Car extends AbstractEntity {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@Column(name="car_number", nullable = false, length = 10)
private String carNumber;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "brand_id", nullable = false)
private CarBrand carBrand;
```

also I have a Spring Data DAO class:

```
public interface CarDAO extends CrudRepository<Car, Long> {

@Override
List<Car> findAll();

List<Car> findAllByCarNumber(String carNumber);
}
```

The problem is the data that put in entity's field which initilize in AbstractEntity (dateOfCreation,  date_of_disable, date_of_update and version_update) are not save into DB when I call `carDAO.save(car)`. 
Can you exmplain what I did wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you annotate the `AbstractEntity` with `@MappedSuperclass`.  Otherwise, Hibernate considers the properties from `AbstractEntity` as not part of the persistence model.